# How can I join to tables and show an random query in mysql and not show same again

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables I need answer from they have same id

- table1 `e107_users`: user_id, user_name, user_image
- table 2 `e107_extended`: user_id, premium, phone

What I need is only to show 5 random selected users and get it to show only if premium.

```
---------  ---------  ---------  ---------  ---------
* Phone *  * Phone *  * Phone *  * Phone *  * Phone *
* image *  * image *  * image *  * image *  * image *
* Name  *  * Name  *  * Name  *  * Name  *  * Name  *
*********  *********  *********  *********  *********
```

The `user_id` should not repeat, so only see the same user once in the query

Comment: Use a left join and a group by.

Comment: Try to use ORDER BY RAND() and LIMIT 5. Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM e107_users u 
JOIN e107_extended e ON u.user_id = e.user_id
WHERE premium = 1
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 5
```

This should do the trick. `ORDER BY RAND()` tells MySQL to do sorting by random, meaning it will just shuffle the entries around. And `LIMIT 5` then limits your result to the 5 first entries. In most circumstances this is something like "largest 5", "minimum 5", but here it is "first 5 out of a total random collection", which means "random 5".

I assume that `e107_users` does not contain any user_id duplicates. Would not make much sense to me.

I also assumed that `e107_users` to `e107_extended` is a **1:1 relation**, but this might be different. However, your question does not provide enough information for this. There is some mentioning about duplicate IDs, but I cannot know where they might occur.

Just in case it is **not a 1:1 relation**, you can use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT * FROM e107_users u 
JOIN e107_extended e ON u.user_id = e.user_id
WHERE premium = 1
GROUP BY u.user_id
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 5
```

This will tell MySQL to use u.user_id (the `user_id` in the `e107_users` table) for grouping elements together. So, if there are multiple elements in `e107_extended` for the same `user_id`, only one will be selected).

**However**, this will probably not shuffle the elements in the extended table. This means that there will always be the same phone number selected. Name and Image will be shuffled, though. I do not know how to fully shuffle everything.

Comment: +1 Though it's worth mentioning `ORDER BY RAND()` wont scale particularly well.

Comment: Thanks for adding this, I am rather an SQL noob, so I did not know this myself, but it’s obvious when you think about it. Shuffling n elements around should require at least O(n), compared to log(n) for normal accesses on indices.